# Is promise.all used to de-capsulate promise value?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying to understand what Promise.all() is doing exactly.

As far as I understand, 
promise is something which holds a return value for asynchronous execution in javascript.

So the values encapsulated(?) by promise is not directly accessible in sychronoous running.

(Terminology warning! I'm going to use analogy to show how I see promise and promise.all())

To get a direct access to the promisified values, 
I need to peel off a shell called promise, which is 
promise.all at the end of asynchronous function.

after this 'peeling-off', I could access to a synchronously available values.

Am I understanding Promise.all correctly?

Thank you so much.

Example is from mdn website.

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
// expected output: Array [3, 42, "foo"]
```

all the promises and just synchronous value (const promise2) were successfully approached by synchronous execution 'console.log()'.

If I don't peel off the promise shell like below,

```
Promise.all([promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
  console.log(promise1)
});
```

The values that js spits out are as below.

Array [42, "foo"]
[object Promise]

Please feel free to criticize my analogy and 
let me know if I understand something wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No. You cannot "unwrap" a promise - there is no way to immediately access a future value. The point of `Promise.all` is to change `promise1.then(value1 => console.log(value1)); promise2.then(value2 => console.log(value2));` into `Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(([value1, value2]) => console.log(value1, value2));` The values are *always* accessed asynchronously inside the `then` callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your analogy is a very interesting one, but I'm sure it's a common perception of how Promises work. Promises are constructs that manage *deffered* values - values that *will* be at some stage, time-dependent. Using the term "wrapping" makes it sound like the value is already there, when in fact it most likely isn't.. yet.

A promise can be used to represent the response from an API, or perhaps a lookup from a database - both of these take **time** - something synchronous code can't handle. You might make a request, and get a promise in response. You can then use this promise as a helper to get the value you intended to receive.

When you call `promise.then(value => ...)`, the `then` function is **waiting** until the value is ready. Inside the promise, something must call `resolve(value)` before the `then` function will fire (note that the promise can also be rejected via `reject`, in which case `promise.catch` would be fired). Here's a full example:

```
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(10);
  }, 2000);
});

promise.then(value => {
  // This fires after about 2 seconds
  console.log(value); // 10
});
```

So the trick here is to visualise that getting results from a promise occurs on a different "thread".. perhaps in a callback or after an `await` call. Also, once a promise has been resolved, calling `then` a second time will return the same value as previously, and it will be *faster*, but still not instant as promises "values" are always asynchronously returned.

**Promise.all** *waits* until *all* the provided promises have resolved. What is returned by `Promise.all` is an array containing all of the resolved results **in order**.  So if you have the following:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(12); // Asynchronously returns 12
const promise2 = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(10);
  }, 2000);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(results => {
 // results will be [12, 10], and will fire after about 2 seconds
});

// here, even though we're after the promise assignments,
// the values to BOTH of the promises are still not yet defined (not resolved)
```

**TLDR;** A promise is a class that records a value once its provided function *resolves*. The `then` method will call its callback with the value once it is set by the promise function (by calling resolve or reject).